# Facebook LikeView asks for logging in

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk

I've been following [official tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button) to integrate my app with new LikeView.

As an logged user (in Android Facebook app), i click the LikeView and it shows another dialog that asks me for logging in. Is second authorization really necessary or am doing something wrong?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmYIM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you turned on Single sign On and Deep linking from developer site for your project ? If not please turn that on.

Comment: It's still asking me once (after install) for logging in, even when i'm logged in Facebook Android app.

Comment: go to the app -> Open Advanced tab and turn on Client OAuth Login And Embedded browser OAuth Login and Let me know the result

Comment: Well, nothing changed, it still asks me for additional login and not offering any other option.

Comment: through your app after providing credentials you are able to login ?

Comment: Thats right, after providing credentials i am able to fully use LikeView.

Comment: lastly turn on Install Insights and Enable Enhanced Interest Targeting in advanced tab itself